# Providing the project root directory for CMake find_package

Tags: c++, cmake

When compiling a project on Windows via CMake, which let's say has the Boost library as a dependency, you might do the following:

1. Run CMake on the project source directory.
2. It says it can't find Boost, but you can specify `ACTUAL_BOOST_ROOT` as a `CACHE PATH` setting,
   which will then be picked up and `BOOST_ROOT` is set, so that `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)` can find the
   Boost libraries.

I would like to do the same for my own library Straph, but for some reason in my own `FindStraph.cmake`, I can't pick up the `STRAPH_ROOT` variable:

```
# Find Straph library
#
# Once done this will define:
#    STRAPH_FOUND         - System has Straph
#    STRAPH_INCLUDE_DIRS  - The Straph include directories
#    STRAPH_LIBRARIES     - The libraries needed to use Straph

find_path(STRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR straph/straph.h
    HINTS
    ${STRAPH_ROOT}/include
    ${STRAPH_ROOT}
)

find_library(STRAPH_LIBRARY NAMES straph libstraph
    HINTS
    ${STRAPH_ROOT}/lib
    ${STRAPH_ROOT}
)

set(STRAPH_LIBRARIES ${STRAPH_LIBRARY})
set(STRAPH_INCLUDE_DIRS ${STRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR})

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(Straph DEFAULT_MSG STRAPH_LIBRARY STRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(STRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR STRAPH_LIBRARY)
```

At least that's the way it seems to me: in my `CMakeLists.txt` I do something like this then:

```
SET(ACTUAL_STRAPH_ROOT CACHE PATH "Location of Straph library")
IF(EXISTS ${ACTUAL_STRAPH_ROOT})
    SET(STRAPH_ROOT ${ACTUAL_STRAPH_ROOT})
ENDIF()
FIND_PACKAGE(Straph REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${STRAPH_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

But it goes and complains that it can't find the libraries even after I set `ACTUAL_STRAPH_ROOT`.

Comment: Your approach seems valid and should work. Add some `message` calls to your `FindStraph` to make sure `STRAPH_ROOT` has the correct value. Then make sure that the `find_*` commands work correctly, that is the stuff you are looking for can indeed be found in the places you are searching.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed elsewhere! Oops! :-D